# iOS: Is there a way to export a file so that only the related App can read/write it?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, nsfilemanager, file-manager

my project is written in swift/swiftui latest version. Right now the user can export any file to the default folder (Files).

My Question: **Is it possible to encrypt/protect the exported file in a way, so that only the app itself can read/write it again?**

Does Swift support this kind of feature?
Or do I have to implement a workaround for that?

Thx! for helping out!

Comment: Against someone who can jailbreak the device, no. Against someone who cannot jailbreak the device, matt's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want anyone else to see the file, don't export to Documents. Put it in Application Support or similar. You are sandboxed, so you are protected from anyone else ever seeing the file.

If the goal is also to prevent the file from ever being backed up, then you can add instructions to that effect. Suppose you have the file's URL as `myFileURL`. Then (supplying mentally the surrounding `do...catch` blocks):

```
var rv = URLResourceValues()
rv.isExcludedFromBackup = true
try myFileURL.setResourceValues(rv)
```

Finally, if the goal is to encrypt a *piece of data*, not really a file per se, then put it in the user's keychain.

Comment: Won't App Support be backed up in an decryptable way? I believe you need to set `isExcludedFromBackup` to avoid that, or am I out of date?

Comment: @RobNapier I'll add the code for that, since it can be a little obscure.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly ***can*** encrypt your file; it's a fair bit of work, but if done correctly it gives you a pretty good guarantee that only your app can read it again.  Generally, @matt's answer will be your best choice -- put it where no other app can access it.  The only use case I can think of where encrypting it & storing it to Documents would be worthwhile is if you need to be able to move (though not read) the file with other apps -- say to e-mail it to yourself or to somebody else who is also using your app.  In that case, the Files app will let you see the files in Documents, and then Share them.

Unless that ability is important, go with @matt's answer.  If you want to go the encryption route, something like [Swift-Sodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium) is a good place to start.